# Supermicro BMC IPMI - How to get hardware specs without OS access

Tags: ipmi, supermicro, bmc

This is my first post in Serverfault for the purpose of trying to get the hardware specs for our supermicro 1U rack server so here it goes:

I have downloaded the IPMIView, IPMICFG, and SMCIPMI utilities -> https://www.supermicro.com/en/solutions/management-software/ipmi-utilities. I have only executed the IPMIView tool but have not been able to get hardware specs - namely, disk storage, ram, cpu, gpu, and nic specs. Only baseboard architecture and product model specs. I have done some reading on the other utilities in the user manuals. I am working on re-imaging the server because the prior OS is encrypted and not going to bother decrypting it, just going to overwrite it with a UA-I image through remote console kvm java application Virtual Media and load-boot from the iso. However, I must get hardware specs and thus far from what I have read I it appears that I cannot get the information I want via supermicro's IPMI utilities and I must have an OS installed to pull this data. Is this correct? Or can I do something about this? All the utilities from what I have learned only function at the BMC interface. Thank you in advance for any insight.

[Image showing Summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUwb3.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can enter IPMI through web interface and check Hardware info in System -> Hardware information.
[image]

Comment: So when I have tried selecting System it just prompts "You need the latest Java(TM) Runtime Environment. Would you like to update now?" and redirects me to System Information->Summary which successfully loads, however it is just firmware, ip address, mac address, etc. I click Cancel for it to do this because when I click OK for the JRE update it just results in "To protect your security, www.oracle.com will not allow Firefox to display the page if another site has embedded it. To see this page, you need to open it in a new window." FRU reading and System information displays, but no System->HW

Comment: Web service is provided through HTTP protocol which is considered as unsafe nowadays, so you should configure your browser to allow it - that is the reason I guess. I use Google Chrome and it promts once that the page is unsafe but allows to go on it, so I suggest you to also use another browser instead of firefox. I edited the post to add a screenshot of the Hardware info tab, so you can be sure you're going in the right direction

Comment: Yep, I tried other browsers and also configured the exception site list in the java control panel security section to allow various iterations of the IP URI. It still for some reason does not display hardware info like what you have showing in your screen shot. I think it is because it is an X9 series BMC chipset and the last firmware release was in 2013 for this model board controller architecture, at least I suppose. I can only get FRU Information and Summary to render, no System HW info.

Comment: Then my last suggestion will be to use console IPMI utility which seems to provide some extended functionality. The one is called SMCIPMITool [here](https://www.supermicro.com/en/solutions/management-software/ipmi-utilities), also available commands are present here. Also if you are able to reboot into BIOS, you can obtain some info there through KVM console, atleast RAM size, CPU and disks are available there usually. If you wanna extended information, you can boot from some LiveCD by mounting virtual image in KVM

Comment: Thanks for the info, will go at it.